# binary tree weird debugging

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, binary-tree

I encountered a debugging issue when I was making program regards binary tree. In the main method of my program, I'm using constructor to create a node called `root`, after that I use `getKey()` method to get the key of the "`previous`" which should refer to "root".

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * BinaryTreeExample from Internet
 * @author xinruchen
 *
 */
import java.util.*;

public class BinaryTreeExample
{
    private static Node root;




    public BinaryTreeExample(int data)
    {
        root = new Node(data);

    }

    public void add(Node parent,Node child, String orientation)
    {
        if(orientation=="left")
        {
           parent.setLeft(child);
        } 
        else if (orientation=="right")
        {
            parent.setRight(child);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int times = sc.nextInt();

        BinaryTreeExample l1=new BinaryTreeExample(3);
        Node previous = root;
        String direction = "";
        System.out.println(previous.getKey());
  }
}

class Node {
    private int key;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;


    Node (int key) {
        this.key = key;
        right = null;
        left = null;

    } // constructor

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node l) {
        if (left == null) {
            this.left = l;
        }
        else {
            left.left = l;
        }
    }

    public Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setRight(Node r ) {
        if (right == null) {
            this.right = r;
        }
        else {
            right.right = r;
        }
    }

    public Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

}
```

If all things go as expected, it should output **"3"**, but it outputs nothing instead. I checked my code and followed the flow of my code and still can't find where the problem is. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: corrected grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch the program, it will wait for user input at the instruction `int times = sc.nextInt();`.

Once you give the input, the program does print `3` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Scanner as you have hard coded the value as 3 and you are not using times or you should use like this

```
        System.out.println("Enter the value");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int times = sc.nextInt();

        BinaryTreeExample l1=new BinaryTreeExample(times);
```

Whenever you request for input you should give a prompt.Although it is not mandatory requirement, but it will avoid the confusion like when the program is waiting for input